# How to split if else error condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a validation with some if/else statements.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["join"])) { 

  if ($userpoint < $lessonpoint) { //pt
    echo "you need more points";
  } //pt

  else { //has enough point


      if ($row['num'] > 0) { //check if user took this lesson
        echo "you took this lesson before.";
      } //check if user took this lesson ends


    else { //then let him apply to database

            //define post:
            $postvalue = (int)$_POST["postvalue"];

            //and check
            if($postvalue == '' || $postvalue <= 0 || $postvalue > $minimumpostvalue || $postvalue == is_int($postvalue)) { //check post
            echo "Error."; 

            } //checkpost ends.


      else { //insert

      $sql = "INSERT into etc... VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

            if($sql){ //to another database

                $artibir = "UPDATE etc.";

                echo "Done.";

            } // to another database
      }//insert
    } //let him apply
  } //has enough point
} //if post isset join
?>
```

This works very well.

But I want to echo out another error message for this condition: `$postvalue > $minimumpostvalue`

While trying it I get lost inside the if/else statements.
Wherever I put new statement I'm having an error.

All variables are defined.

Where and how can I place `$postvalue > $minimumpostvalue` to echo a different error message?

Comment: Your code may work well but it is not coded well - like how a dish can taste well but its recipe is so bad that the original cook can't understand it, which is what is happening. Try to experiment how you can write it better. I suggest starting with indent.

Comment: This already is and will become even more a maintainance nightmare. The very fact that you get lost in if-else-statments yells: code smell. Refactor your code into function tops 15 lines, avoid else statements as often as you can, and return early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//and check
if ($postvalue > $minimumpostvalue) { //check exception
   echo "Error 1."; 
} elseif ($postvalue == '' || $postvalue <= 0 || $postvalue == is_int($postvalue)) { //check the rest
      echo "Error 2."; 
} //checkpost ends.
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in C:\\www\x\test.php on line 254` line 254 is: `else {` before `$sql`

Comment: My code segment is fine. You may have an unmatched brace somewhere else.

Comment: This is where I stuck. Code is working when it's written like my question post but every correct edit drops an error which I can't figure out.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["join"])) {

   if ($userpoint < $lessonpoint) { //pt
     echo "you need more points";
   } //pt

    else { //has enough point

         if ($row['num'] > 0) { //check if user took this lesson
             echo "you took this lesson before.";
         } //check if user took this lesson ends

        else { //then let him apply to database

             //define post:
             $postvalue = (int) $_POST["postvalue"];

             //and check
                  if ($postvalue == '' || $postvalue <= 0 || $postvalue > $minimumpostvalue || $postvalue == is_int($postvalue)) { //check post
                        if ($postvalue > $minimumpostvalue) {
                            echo "Another Error.";
                         } 
                        else {
                           echo "Error.";
                         }

                   } //checkpost ends.

                  else { //insert

                       $sql = "INSERT into etc... VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

                       if ($sql) { //to another database

                           $artibir = "UPDATE etc.";

                           echo "Done.";

                       } // to another database
                  } //insert
              } //let him apply
     } //has enough point
} //if post isset join
?>
```

Comment: `if ($postvalue == '' || $postvalue == is_int($postvalue) || $postvalue <= 0 || $postvalue > $minimumpostvalue) `  this will be logically perfect :)

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in C:\\www\x\test.php on line 246` line 246 is: `else {` before `$sql`

Comment: please check the number of opening and closing braces in your code. That seems to be incorrect upon first impression.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I have 9 both opening and closing braces. weird.

Answer (score 2):

This is another variation without exceptions.

As soon as $valid becomes false, it will skip the next validation.

```
<?php
$valid = true;
$error = '';

if ($valid && !isset($_POST["join"])) {
    $error = 'Not a join post request';
    $valid = false;
}

if ($valid && ($userpoint < $lessonpoint)) {
    $error = 'You need more points';
    $valid = false;
}

...

if($valid) {
    // Database insert; redirect
} else {
    // User error feedback
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested code, and more an example of how to avoid nested `if` statements.

The point is to find to state the conditions you have an error state early and exit as soon as you can, at best by throwing an exception and avoiding `else` statements.

For simplicity I used only `\RunTimeException()`, yet I would most likely define my own exception depending on the case. The exception then can be caught and depending on their type show a different error page.

```
/**
 * @param int $postvalue
 * @param int $minimumpostvalue
 */
function saveToDatabase($postvalue)
{
    if ($postvalue == '' || $postvalue <= 0 || $postvalue == is_int($postvalue)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Error 2');
    }

    $sql = "INSERT into etc... VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    if ($sql) {
        $artibir = "UPDATE etc.";
    }
}

if (!isset($_POST["join"])) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Not a join post request');
}

if ($userpoint < $lessonpoint) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('You need more points');
}

$userHasTakenCourse = $row['num'] > 0;
if ($userHasTakenCourse) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('User has already taken the course.');
}

$postvalue = (int) $_POST["postvalue"];
if ($postvalue > $minimumpostvalue) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Error 1');
}

saveToDatabase($postvalue);
```